# Deserializing array of JSONElement back to a concrete list not working when using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, jsonserializer, .net-7.0

I have a problem when deserializing an object. The object has a property (`data`) that is a list of `JSONElement`. I'm doing:

```
using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));

var e = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("data");
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyItem>>(e);
```

The serialized `result` variable has the following content:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":245,
         "number":14,
         "name":"Test"
      }
   ],
   "totalCount":-1,
   "groupCount":-1,
   "summary":null
}
```

And the `MyItem` class is as follows:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `data` variable is a list with `x` items. However all items are empty instances.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share minimum reproducible code ? a sample of your json (or result ) and MyItem class would aid in helping you better

Comment: Try extracting the JSON string from the JSONElement objects and deserialize each string separately. You can do this using a loop.

Comment: **[I tried your code and it works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMzAcL)**, for a simply `MyItem` class with 2 public props of types `int` and `string` that I constructed. You really need to show us more of your code.

Comment: Sample JSON and class added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that your data is using lowercase property names which are not translated to the property names in your class with the default deserialization settings.

```
using System.Text.Json;

dynamic result = new
{
    data = new dynamic[] {
        new {
            id = 245,
            number = 14,
            name = "Test"
        }
    },
    totalCount = -1,
    groupCount = -1
};

using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));

var e = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("data");
List<MyItem> data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyItem>>(e);

Console.WriteLine($"{data.First().Id} {data.First().Number} {data.First().Name}");
```

The above code won't work with your `MyItem` class, but try this instead:

```
public class MyItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If it works, either use the `JsonPropertyName` on all your properties or else consider changing your deserialization options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I set `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true` of `JsonSerializerOptions` and it works perfectly now!! Grazzi :)

Answer (score 0):

Everythig can be done in one string of code. You just need to  set PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true of JsonSerializerOptions. Better to make it in a startup file.

```
List<MyItem> data =  JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement.GetProperty("data")
.Deserialize<List<MyItem>>();
```